# "Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I have client and server application running on different ports.

I have tried adding basic 64 encoded(clientId:secret) authorization basic in request header.

Server side code
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resource server API will need Authorization header Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}. Auth headers basic will be used to get access_token.